# Update is not Happening while using accepts_nested_attributes_for in Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to update accepts_nested_attributes_for fields in ActiveRecord using Rails4 but its not happening.

My Event class,

```
t.string :name
      t.string :slug
      t.string :description
      t.integer :total_capacity
      t.string :url
      t.integer :invite_only
      t.integer :is_public
      t.integer :event_type_id
      t.integer :event_ticketing
      t.integer :company_id
      t.integer :client_id
      t.attachment :display_photo
```

and EventTiming class,

```
t.date :date
      t.time :start_time
      t.time :end_time
      t.integer :event_id
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :company_id
```

i have done,
in event class

```
has_many :event_timings, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :event_timings, allow_destroy: true
```

And in controller,

```
def event_params
  params.require(:event).permit!
end
```

edit.html.erb

```
<%= f.fields_for :event_timings do |builder| %>
   <%= render :partial => 'events/event_timing_fields', 
              :locals => { :f => builder } %>
<% end %>
```

Log info for update is,

```
Started PATCH "/events/test-dance" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-24 16:44:46 +0530
Processing by EventsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"/O06IfwhCDecm//oGuWwGXAIRaCjwbl0s/7CZucOySU=", "event"=>{"name"=>"Test Dance", "url"=>"www.mink7.com", "event_type_id"=>"", "total_capacity"=>"100", "event_ticketing"=>"0", "event_timings_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"date(1i)"=>"2014", "date(2i)"=>"12", "date(3i)"=>"24", "start_time(1i)"=>"2000", "start_time(2i)"=>"1", "start_time(3i)"=>"1", "start_time(4i)"=>"15", "start_time(5i)"=>"29", "end_time(1i)"=>"2000", "end_time(2i)"=>"1", "end_time(3i)"=>"1", "end_time(4i)"=>"15", "end_time(5i)"=>"29", "user_id"=>"2", "id"=>"1"}}, "description"=>"Come and enjoy...!!!"}, "commit"=>"Next", "id"=>"test-dance"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 2 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Company Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `companies`.* FROM `companies` WHERE `companies`.`user_id` = 2
  Event Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `events`.* FROM `events` WHERE `events`.`slug` = 'test-dance' ORDER BY `events`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  EventTiming Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `event_timings`.* FROM `event_timings` WHERE `event_timings`.`event_id` = 1 AND `event_timings`.`id` IN (1)
   (0.3ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/events/test-dance
Completed 302 Found in 21ms (ActiveRecord: 2.2ms)
```

my update function is straight forward

```
def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.update(event_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Please help me!!!

Comment: Post the log info while updating.

Comment: And also what are your `event attributes` and `event_timing attributes`?

Comment: i have Event and EventTiming two models...!!!

Comment: I see that.Post the `attributes` of those two models.

Comment: Can you also provide your `update` method in your controller, please.

Comment: @RubyOnRails can you post your full form? and it's not a good idea to use the bang version of permit(i know it will permit all the attributes but still you should specify them instead)

Comment: @Mandeep, Yes thanks for your suggestion. For your information i just wanted to test it so that ill achieve first save/update then i will change it later point....!!!

Comment: @RubyOnRails can you post your full form? And use a debugger in your update action just before you are updating your record and then write event_params in console check if all your attributes are being permitted or not cuz I can see event_type_id is nil in your logs